# Writing TestComplete Plug-in with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, testcomplete

Is it possible to write Test Complete plug-ins in C#? I see that you can write some extension for WPF controls in their documentation. However, can I write full fledged plugins? I am on version 8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestComplete is a native COM-based application and, therefore, a custom plug-in should be a native dll with the COM architecture as well. Theoretically, it is possible to create it in C#, but I think that a possible result does not worth efforts. Information on the supported platforms (Visual C++ and Delphi) can be found in the [Supported Development Tools](http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/12983/) article.

Please note that there are some samples included in the [TestComplete SDK](http://smartbear.com/support/downloads/testcomplete/sdk/) and some user-contributed examples for older versions of the tool:

- [Real-world TestComplete Plug-ins, Part I](http://blog.smartbear.com/post/06-04-04/real-world-testcomplete-plug-ins-part-i/)
- [Real-world TestComplete Plug-ins Part II](http://blog.smartbear.com/post/06-04-23/real-world-testcomplete-plug-ins-part-ii/)
- [Real-world TestComplete Plug-ins Part III - Extended Colors Plug-in](http://blog.smartbear.com/post/06-06-01/real-world-testcomplete-plug-ins-part-iii---extended-colors-plug-in/)
- [Real-world TestComplete Plug-ins Part IV - ODT Declaration Generator](http://blog.smartbear.com/post/06-09-17/real-world-testcomplete-plug-ins-part-iv---odt-declaration-generator/)

I guess the current API is mostly the same, for the sake of backward compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed response. While I definitely agree that it might be messy to deal with a COM wrapper in .net, I feel it would be very useful as there is a lot of interest in UI testing specifically in wpf/asp.net applications. There are other projects that provide it. May be something for a open source effort. Thanks again !